# MouseMotionListener: mouse and trackpad give different results

Tags: java, mouseevent, mouse, mousemotionlistener

I'm using a MouseMotionListener to draw on a JComponent.

```
addMouseMotionListener(new MouseMotionAdapter() {
    public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent e) {
        System.out.println("DRAG ["+(i++)+"]");
        grid.handleMouseEvent(e);
    }
});
```

When I perform a mouse drag with my trackpad, I get the intended behavior. When I do the same thing with my actual mouse (USB), the drawing 'lags' quite a bit. I noticed that the source of the 'lag' comes from the `mouseDragged` method not getting invoked when I move my mouse too quickly. **Why does this only happen with my mouse and not the trackpad?**

[Here](https://gfycat.com/UltimateLimpingEthiopianwolf) is a (19s) GIF of two launches of the program. The first one shows the laggy drawing with the mouse. The second uses the trackpad and works as intended.

I understand that this may end up not being a problem with `MouseMotionListener` or even Java. If that is the case, I apologize. Maybe I could be redirected to another resource. Thanks!

Comment: This is most likely an issue with either mouse driver or mouse hardware and the resolution (number) of updates it's willing to produce during a drag operaion

Comment: Thank you! My mouse was previously at a 1000Hz polling rate. I reduced it to match the trackpad's 125Hz and they behave the same. It's interesting that decreasing the polling rate fixed it. Maybe the listener couldn't handle 1000Hz.

Comment: I'm not sure it's an issue with the listener, might be spamming the EDT or the API (high or low level) might be filtering out repeated events within small period of time